# My node.js server hangs - until I issue Ctrl+C

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-ec2, window

I have a nodejs + mysql application running on AWS on windows (EC2, RDP). I often get the above issue. Googling suggests that it may be due to jobs running in the background. here is something I found in "It sounds like you've forked a process which is blocking things, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is killing that."

Could this be the reason? can it be something else?
If so, what action can I take?
Is there a way to view all jobs that are running in the background?

Comment: Something is, apparently, blocking the event loop. Without seeing the actual code is hard to say what may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code it's hard to guess, but if you just need the application to end, you could invoke `process.exit()` and it will exit.